# How to map one property to another in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, azure-activedirectory

Is it possible to configure a property in AD to be mapped to another property using Azure AD Connect? Or does it have to be done via PowerShell?

The end goal being to map the value of `IPPhone` to `TelephoneNumber` so it is exposed in the profile cards in Office applications.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via Azure AD Connect using the Synchronization Rule Editor.

[How-To Video](https://youtu.be/2vE_q-Grcrc?t=560)